# Creating pandas dataframe with tuples per row but with missing columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have an operation that outputs a series of tuples like
`[('a',1.0), ('c', 2.5)]`. It does this for a lot of inputs, so the outputs would look like

```
[('a',1.0), ('c', 2.5)]
[('b',1.5), ('c', 2.5)]
[('a', 5.0), ('b',1.5), ('c', 2.75)]
```

which should output a dataframe that looks like

```
>>> df
     a     b     c
0    1.0   NaN   2.5
1    NaN   1.5   2.5
2    5.0   1.5   2.75
```

However, **the column names are not known beforehand**, so at some point the data generation, I could end up with some `('z',12.0)`.

I think the simplest way would be to create a dataframe for each row and concatenate the dataframes:

```py
df_list = []
for row in rows:
     tuple_result = f(row)
     df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(...)) # generate a single-row dataframe
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

and this will take care of all the NaNs and column names. However, I will be doing this for several rows and I think this approach will be unnecessarily memory-intensive.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your can use a list comprehension, converting each row of tuples into a dictionary.

```
my_data = [
    [('a',1.0), ('c', 2.5)],
    [('b',1.5), ('c', 2.5)],
    [('a', 5.0), ('b',1.5), ('c', 2.75)]
]

>>> pd.DataFrame([dict(row) for row in my_data])
     a    b     c
0  1.0  NaN  2.50
1  NaN  1.5  2.50
2  5.0  1.5  2.75
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame([dict(row) for row in my_data * 100000])
# 559 ms ± 92 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit pd.DataFrame(map(dict, my_data * 100000))
# 438 ms ± 25.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%%timeit
df_list = []
for row in my_data * 100000:
     df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(dict(row), index=[0])) 
df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
# 6min 11s ± 1min 54s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: In recent version of `pandas`, you might pass `map` objs also `pd.DataFrame(map(dict, my_data))`, I think it gets so clean ;p

Comment: Yes, that appears to be more efficient and potentially more readable.